# How to protect a Success page from direct access in NextJS with app router?

Tags: next.js, app-router

I'm using NextJS 13.5.2 and the new app router. I just implemented a classic PayPal checkout process and, once the payment is successfully, I'm redirecting the user to the Success page.

Both the page which starts the checkout process and the Success page are client side. To redirect the user I'm using:

`checkoutPage.tsx`

```
"use client"

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"

...
export default function CheckoutPage() {
   ...
   <PayPalButton
       onApprove={data => (
           fetch(`/api/orders/capture/${data.orderID}`, {...})
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(orderData => {
                  const email = orderData.payer.email_address
                                                                                     
                  router.replace(`/order/success?email=${email}`)
            })/> Click to Pay <PayPalButton>
   ...
```

`successPage.tsx`

```
"use client"

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation"

export default function SuccessPage() {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()

    const email = searchParams.get("email")
    return (
        <main>
            <h1 className="mb-8">
                Thank you. Your email: {email}
            </h1>
        </main>
    )
}
```

#### How can I protect the Success page from the direct access in the url?

Maybe setting a cookie with the `orderID` in the backend and then read and compare the cookie in the Success page? Can I read the cookie client side? Using the `cookies` build in method [seems not possible](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a server-side verification process. Using cookies alone is not a secure way to prevent unauthorised access because cookies can be manipulated by users. You can generate a unique token for each successful transaction and store it in a database or session store on server-side. Then during redirection, instead of the email parameter in the URL you can use this token as a parameter.
Then when a user accesses the Success page, validate the token by checking if it exists and is associated with a valid, completed order or session. If the token is valid, you can show the Success page with the relevant order information. If the token is invalid or doesn't exist, deny access or redirect the user to an error page. This approach will ensure that only users with a valid and verified token can access the Success page. It will also prevent users from directly accessing the Success page via the URL unless they have successfully completed the PayPal checkout process.
Give something like this a try,

```js
// checkoutPage.tsx
// ...
export default function CheckoutPage() {
   // ...
   <PayPalButton
       onApprove={data => (
           fetch(`/api/orders/capture/${data.orderID}`, {...})
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(orderData => {
                  const token = orderData.transactionToken // Generated secure token
                  router.replace(`/order/success?token=${token}`)
            })/> Click to Pay <PayPalButton>
   // ...
}

// successPage.tsx
// ...
export default function SuccessPage() {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const token = searchParams.get("token")

    // Send a request to the server to verify the token
    // If token is valid, display success information, otherwise handle invalid access
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It seems a good solution. Thanks